# Can I manually/programmatically put the battery charging on hold?

Tags: battery, charging

I have a 2016 MBP and due to my work-from-home setup I need to use an external monitor for working, which force the Mac to use the discrete graphic card and thus a faster battery drainage (together with other software).

Given the advertised feature that should put the battery charging on hold at 80%, the last weekend I have updated the OS from 10.14 to 11.1, but that feature doesn't seems to work as expected: even if enabled (by default), it always charge up to 100%; sometime it happend to actually stop charging, but after a few seconds it ramped again up to 100% automatically.

My question is, is there a way to force that behavior ? I've looked at `pmset`'s man-page, but I haven't seen anything related.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a tool that I've seen recommended by others:

https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente

It can limit your charging to specific percentages. However, I've not used it myself.

Comment: It does seems to work with my machine, but it put me on the right track. Thank you!

Comment: Just a note it took a little work for me to get this working - involving disabling the System Preferences solution and restarting - but that it did start working

Answer (score 3):

Not really an already available solution, but Ezekiel put me on the right track: *AlDente*, while (currently; I've opened an issue) not working for me, attempt to writes a `BCLM` value in the SMC controller. So I've tried a different solution and found [this one](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm) which does the job (from CLI).

Answer (score 0):

Source: [A guide on limiting macOS battery charging to at most 80%.](https://gist.github.com/NightMachinery/402863ccf37515a804b2f5fa15672375)

#### Limiting macOS charging to 80%:

##### 1. Install `smc`:

To install `smc` on your macOS, follow these steps:

```shell
# Install smcfancontrol using Homebrew
brew install --cask smcfancontrol

# Copy the 'smc' binary to /usr/local/bin/ for global access
sudo cp '/Applications/smcFanControl.app/Contents/Resources/smc' /usr/local/bin/
```

##### 2. Update `sudo` permissions:

To avoid entering your password every time you use the `smc` command with `sudo`, you can update the sudoers file.

1. Open the sudoers file using the `visudo` command:

```shell
sudo visudo
```

2. Scroll to the bottom of the file and add the following line. Replace `username` with your actual macOS username:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/smc
```

3. Save and exit the editor.

##### 3. Using the Zsh Functions:

Make sure you have added the provided Zsh functions to your `.zshrc` or another Zsh configuration file.

```shell
# Apple Silicon laptops with firmware > 13.0 have a native charge threshold that does not required any userspace daemon running.
# This native limit works even when the laptop is sleeping or powered off therefore it is preferable to the userspace daemon.
# Nonetheless, it only works with fixed thresholds (80% as upper limit and 70% as lower limit).
# CHWA key is the one used to enable/disable the native limit. 01 = 80% limit, 00 = no limit
##
typeset -g smc_command="/usr/local/bin/smc"
typeset -g smc_charge_limit_key="CHWA"
typeset -g smc_charge_limit_status_on="01"
typeset -g smc_charge_limit_status_off="00"

function battery-charge-limit-enable {
    if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
        if [[ ! -e "${smc_command}" ]]; then
            echo 'SMC command not found!'
            return 1
        fi

        sudo "${smc_command}" -k "${smc_charge_limit_key}" -w "${smc_charge_limit_status_on}"
    else
        echo "Not a Darwin system."
    fi
}

function battery-charge-limit-disable {
    if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
        if [[ ! -e "${smc_command}" ]]; then
            echo 'SMC command not found!'
            return 1
        fi

        sudo "${smc_command}" -k "${smc_charge_limit_key}" -w "${smc_charge_limit_status_off}"
    else
        echo "Not a Darwin system."
    fi
}

function battery-charge-limit-status {
    if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
        if [[ ! -e "${smc_command}" ]]; then
            echo 'SMC command not found!'
            return 1
        fi

        local status_raw="$(sudo "${smc_command}" -k "${smc_charge_limit_key}" -r)"

        # Extract the bytes using regex
        if [[ "$status_raw" =~ 'bytes ([0-9]+)' ]]; then
            status_raw=$match[1]
        fi

        case "$status_raw" in
            "${smc_charge_limit_status_on}")
                echo "on"
                ;;
            "${smc_charge_limit_status_off}")
                echo "off"
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Unknown ${smc_charge_limit_key} status: $status_raw"
                ;;
        esac
    else
        echo "Not a Darwin system."
    fi
}
```

- To **enable** the battery charge limit:

  ```shell
  battery-charge-limit-enable
  ```
- To **disable** the battery charge limit:

  ```shell
  battery-charge-limit-disable
  ```
- To **check the status** of the battery charge limit:

  ```shell
  battery-charge-limit-status
  ```

With these functions in place and `smc` installed, you can easily manage the battery charge limit of your macOS device from the terminal.

##### Compatibility

This needs an updated firmware on an Apple Silicon machine.

##### See Also

- [Battery charge limiter for Apple Silicon Macbook devices](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery)

  - [Issue: added support for firmware-based thresholds](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery/pull/163)